# How can I handle click event on buttons at bottom bar?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I made an application with a bottom bar, containing three different buttons, in its main activity. For example, one of the buttons is used to delete a student from a roll book. How can I perform the delete operation every time the user wants to delete a student? The only thing I want to know is how can I handle the click event every time the delete button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout xml, add an android:click property to the delete button, such as android:click="delete".  Then in your activity, create a function

public void delete(View param)

That function will be called when the delete is clicked.  Repeat for the other two buttons.